# Bank Account Program Issues with build and getting started

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors

Onto another program.  this is a program that simulates a bank account.  I need help with the showing of the balance, withdraw, and deposit.  how do i get this to show the final balance after the withdraw/deposit?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BACCOUNT.H"

    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {
        double amount = 0.0;
        double withrdraw = 0.0;
        double deposit = 0.0;
        string name;
        double startamount = 100.00;
        double balance = 0.0;


        cout << "name: ";
        cin >> name;

        cout << "initial balance: " << startamount <<endl;


        cout << "deposit? ";
        cin >> amount;
        cout << "withdraw? ";
        cin >> amount;


        cout << "balance for " << name  << " is " << balance << endl;

        system ("pause");

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << "balance for " << name () << " is " << balance()
    <<endl;
```

By putting parenthesis after them, you're trying to call `name` and `balance` like functions, but they're `string`s. Remove the parenthesis.

More importantly, what made you think you *had to* include parenthesis there? There may be a fundamental piece of C++ that you're confused about (functions) that you should seek to fully understand.

Comment: I just updated my code above...how do i get it to calculate the end balance?

Comment: You tell me! It's your assignment, after all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I hope you understand that the community here is going to be *more than willing* to help you with problems where you've shown your best effort, but aren't able to understand something that is going on.
Where we're *not* willing to help, is to do things *for you* that you should be doing yourself, without any effort on your part.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I'm just really struggling.  If you think im slacking off, don't respond to my post. @Jonathon Reinhart.

Comment: That's fine. But StackOverflow is not the place to learn how to code. That's why there are courses and books and tutorials. We're here to help with specific out-of-the-ordinary problems that arise while you're developing.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to call `name` and `balance` as functions here:

```
cout << "balance for " << name () << " is " << balance() <<endl;
                          ^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^
```

but `name` is a `string` and `balance` is a `double`. This edit will fix the problem:

```
cout << "balance for " << name << " is " << balance <<endl;
```